# Mit oder ohne Artikel?

Tags: word-usage

Welcher Satz wäre korrekt für eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit?

> Die Einleitung beinhaltet die Grundidee, These, Zielsetzung sowie
>   Zielgruppe und Industrierelevanz.

oder

> Die Einleitung beinhaltet die Grundidee, die These, die Zielsetzung
>   sowie die Zielgruppe und die Industrierelevanz.

Comment: Ich stimme für deinen ersten Vorschlag. Der zweite klingt furchtbar. Aber vielleicht sogar ganz ohne Artikel - ich denke, da kommt noch was dahinter wie "... Industrierelevanz von ..."

Comment: In der ersten Version müsste auch "die" vor "Grundidee" verschwinden, damit sich das Ganze harmonisch anhört.

Comment: Dritte Variante: Wie die erste, aber nach dem "sowie" den Artikel einmal wiederholen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal korrekt sind beide.
Variante 1 ist flüssiger.
Persönlich würde ich auch noch das erste "die" streichen:

> Die Einleitung beinhaltet Grundidee, These, Zielsetzung sowie Zielgruppe und Industrierelevanz.

(Und "beinhaltet" ist auch nicht schön -- wie wär's mit

- stellt vor
- erläutert
- beschreibt
- erklärt
- ...

?)

Comment: ich finde, dass ein "stellt vor" für den Wortfluss erst recht die Artikel benötigt. Denn das "vor" kommt erst nach der gesamten Aufzählung. Und ich würde die Klammern & ? um den Vorschlag entfernen.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Und ja, du hast recht; "beinhaltet" klingt wirklich nicht schön. Ich nehme stattdessen "erläutert".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Der OP hat ja nach seinen Beispielen gefragt. Mit "stellt vor" wäre es ein anderer Satz, aber "... stellt Grundidee, These, ... vor" klingt für mich trotzdem besser als mit Artikeln. Die Vorschläge in Klammern haben mit der Frage selbst eigentlich nichts zu tun, sondern sind (je nach Blickwinkel) Bonus oder Klugscheisserei ...

Comment: @user41324: die Beispiele finde ich gut, ich habe zu einem meine persönliche inhaltliche Meinung geschrieben - und für den Rest *meine* Präfernenz der Darstellung. So sieht es für mich wie "eigentlich kein Bestandteil der Antwort" aus. Was daraus wird, liegt erst irgendwann später bei mir, wenn ich denke "geht hübscher" - nachdem ich meinen Hinweis zur Optik gab. Ist ja nicht meine Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde dir vorschlagen den ersten Vorschlag zu nehmen. Wenn du dich in die Lage des Lesers versetzt, ist einem wohler als beim zweiten Vorschlag. Es sind zu viele Wörter und man verliest sich eher.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich stolpere über den zweiten Satz "ist einem wohler als" - der zweite Halbsatz ist grammatikalisch korrekt, nur scheint er mit dem ersten nur bedingt zu passen: Dass der OP sich in die Lage des Lesers versetzt lässt mich wohler fühlen? Ich befürworte eine präzisere Formulierung der angestrebten Aussage.

Comment: Stolper ich auch drüber. "Wenn Du Dich ... versetzt ist Dir wohler" wäre logisch, nicht ist <b> einem</b> wohler. Aber wenn Du dich hineinversetzt ist Dir vielleicht wohler, als wenn Du dich nicht hineinversetzt. Das geht sprachlich kreuz und quer. Dass man sich bei mehr Wörtern, zumal trivialen Artikeln eher verliest halte ich auch für eine gewagte Behauptung.

Comment: @user unknown streber!!